# iOS SwuftUI - get firebase messaging user token

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this code:

```
@main
    struct AppName: App {
        
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
                    .task {
                        
                        print("tttttt")
                        
                        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
                          if let error = error {
                            print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
                          } else if let token = token {
                            print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
                          }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

"tttttt" gets printed out but I don't get the user token nor any error message.

I'm already using google sign in so I guess I have set up firebase sdk correctly

Please help

Comment: Completion handlers are very different to the new async await methods (What task is using). You should watch “Meet async/await” from the WWDC videos

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should be doing in a View. Create an ObservableObject type that has the FCM token as an @Published variable. Then in whatever View is internal to your App, just instantiate the ObservableObject and pass it to sub-views as needed as an EnvironmentObject. Then you can reference your Firebase related values in views without issue.

Comment: I'm new to ios development and it's dumb compared to android development, much more stable but extremely dumb and unintuitive. I don't know how to do what you've said

Comment: I would recommend starting by making some basic views- no Firebase stuff involved. Giving a working demonstration of what you’re asking for requires three different files, and will be unintuitive to you unless you already familiarize yourself with what you can do in SwiftUI. If you really like, I can give a code example, but it seems like you’re just trying to go from 0 to 100 without the practice in between. Once you get the hang, SwiftUI is very intuitive and satisfying

Comment: Can you show me where I can learn all which is necessary? I've watched the "2021 SwiftUI Tutorial for Beginners (3.5 hour Masterclass)" and it's not enough to do what you've said